# How can I create a large list from a small list in jython?

Tags: python, list, jython-2.5

If I have a limited list of 15 pics. And I want to create a larger list of say 100 pics that are random copies of the 15 pics. Could I do something like

```
list = randrange(img)
for i in randrange(img, 0, 99)?
```

I'm just not sure how to create a large list?

Answer (score 0):

You take a sample from a larger list by concatenating multiple instances of the original list.

Here's a quick and dirty attempt that appears to work.  Only tested it with integers, though.

```
import random

def larger_sample(list, size):
  n = len(list)
  list_multiplier = (size/n + 1)
  assert n*list_multiplier >= size
  return random.sample(list * list_multiplier, size)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  list = [1,2,3,4,5]

  for length in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]:
    l = larger_sample(list, length)
    assert len(l) == length
    print l
```